# Is it bad to include header and footer as a template?

Tags: php, html, css

I was wondering if it's the right thing to include the tags like  etc via another page.

What I mean by that is:

```
<?php include_once("header.php")?>
The content for each individual page
<?php include_once("footer.php")?>
```

Header.php contains:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>My Website</title>
</head>
<body>
```

Footer.php contains:

```
</body>
</html>
```

I am using it that way because when I have a lot of pages, it's a lot easier to just change one/two page(s). That way I spare time.

But the question is, is it bad to use a "template" style for my website?

( I saw some similair questions like this one but they didn't really answer my question, that's why I started a new topic - Sorry if it's wrong )

Comment: i've seen this pattern, i forgot what it's called. The other pattern is to have a layout file with header and footer and inject the content to a placeholder in it.

Comment: I think it is a good practice. better code readability is less bugs. also if you need to change something in the header or footer you don't miss a single page if you are using includes

Comment: I've been a web dev for 12+ years and that's how I do all my dynamic sites.

Comment: So it doesn't slow a website down or something for example?

Comment: any framework or php application uses same idea (include files), so for your case its just right approach and continue this style to prevent code duplicate easier maintenance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No problem with this I think - it's certainly better than duplicating the same content across multiple pages. [Don't Repeat Yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) is a core tenant of programming, and this approach helps in that regard. The performance impact of the PHP includes is absolutely minimal and not worth worrying about, compared to advantage of easier maintenance.

You might be able to go further still though. Do you really need to repeat the includes on every page ? If all the pages have identical headers and footers, then you could make just one page that has them, and an area for dynamic content in the middle instead (this is the approach ASP.NET takes).

Comment: Thanks, didn't know something like that existed :P

Answer (score 1):

No, this is great. You will actually find there are more and more things you would like to move into included files, for example the sidebar for your website could be in its own file. This is exactly what PHP what made for, to allow for easier maintenance of your website.

Answer (score 1):

Any PHP will be slower than only HTML.  For example people use cacheing plugins for wordpress sites, so just HTML will be requested and the php server wont have to work as hard, and the page will be quicker.  But the benefits of using PHP clearly outweigh this with the popularity of wordpress.

All php calls are made once, so multiple calls of php is not like multiple calls for css files or JavaScript.

As the site grows you will be happy to make one change that will affect all pages, rather than have to change each page.  A simple example is a seasonal greeting in the header.  Simple to ad and take away with your template. not so without.  And that is before the more obvious link changes.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good direction, just don't repeat yourself. Anyway, to get some more robustness from this templating idea you can try to take a look on the following libraries:

Twig : http://twig.sensiolabs.org
Smarty: http://www.smarty.net

Comment: Thanks, I will give it smarty a try when I have time ;)